# aiogram python Не могу отловить событие inline кнопки

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

У меня проблема, мне нужно создать inline кнопку, которая перенаправит пользователя на сайт.
Кнопку я создаю, всё корректно:

```
inline_pay = InlineKeyboardButton('Перейти к оплате', callback_data='pay', url='https://www.google.com')
```

Но мне нужно отловить это действие, чтобы записать в базу данных информацию о том, что эта кнопка была нажата пользователем.
При помощи callback_query_handler не получается отловить это событие.
Подскажите, как это можно сделать при помощи inline кнопки или может есть другие способы?

*Мне главное, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку я смог отловить это событие и записать в базу данных.

Comment: Такое реализовать в боте невозможно, в кнопке должен быть либо url, либо callback_data. Можете попробовать установить в коллбэке какие-то другие данные и отлавливать их уже на сайте

Comment: К сожалению, у меня отсутствует возможность отлавливать переходы на самом сайте)

Comment: @Виктор, такое не возможно реализовать. Обдумайте занова логику кода, зачем допустим вам отлавливать нажатие кнопки? Для статистики, или ....? А если человек откроет сайт и не оплатить ничего?

Comment: Как самый крайнии варинт - мидлваре, но повторюсь, только в крайнем случае

Answer (score 0):

Телеграм дает на выбор url/callback

Код должен быть таким:

markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()

markup.add(InlineKeyboardButton('Перейти к оплате', url='https://www.google.com')

Обращаю ваше внимание на валидность указанной ссылки. В противном случае телеграм будет ругаться мол не могу распарсить кнопку.